# Search box not taking custom display template

Tags: search, display-template

I am wanting to change the text inside the search box so I created a new display template and referenced it in the master page like so:

```
<SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart UseSiteCollectionSettings="true" runat="server" EmitStyleReference="False" RenderTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/SLC_SearchBox.js" ServerInitialRender="True" ShowQuerySuggestions="False" TryInplaceQuery="False" UseSharedSettings="True" ChromeType="None" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="" __WebPartId="{C71B7AD7-5501-463F-A3B9-6E1E5B09A619}" id="g_c71b7ad7_5501_463f_a3b9_6e1e5b09a619"/>
```

yet the text isn't changing.
The search settings are as follows:
search center URL:/Search
which search results page should queries be sent to>
Send queries to custom results page URL
Results page URL: /Search/Pages/results.aspx

Comment: did you publish your display template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing ServerInitialRender="True" to "False" in the master page.